# VBA - Loop through Recordset fails

Tags: vba

I have a requirement where in I am looping through a record set without using EOF.
But it fails to pick up the 2nd element, saying it couldn't find it in the collection.

This is my code:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)
 Debug.Print (rs(0)) 'Works
 Debug.Print (rs(1)) 'Says Item cannot be found
```

But rs.RecordCount gives an value of 2

I am trying to get those values and add it to a listbox

```
Total1 = rs.RecordCount
Total2 = Total1 - 1


If Total1 > 0 Then
    For j = 0 To Total2
        Value = rs(j) ' fails when j = 1
            If Value <> "" Then                
                With RequiredReportType.RT_ListBox
                    .AddItem Value
                End With
            End If
        Value = ""     
    Next
End If
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Doesn't record set use stuff like `.MoveNext` to change rows? And the number in the bracket to index the row item (column)?

Comment: @Noceo, that is called a `record field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer, it needs the `.movenext`

Here goes the code,

```
With rs

 Do Until rs.EOF

     ReqValue = rs.Fields(0).Value

     If ReqValue <> "" Then

                With RequiredReportType.RT_ListBox

                        .AddItem ReqValue

                End With

            End If


     rs.MoveNext

 Loop

End With
```